# LinkedIn JS API token exchange to REST token

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I am using the Python python-oauth2. I am receiving an error when trying to exchange my tokens. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

client = oauth.Client(consumer)

client.request(access_token_url, "POST", headers={'xoauth_oauth2_access_token':'XXXXXXXXXX'})
({'status': '400', 'content-length': '83', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'date': 'Thu, 10 May 2012 22:28:38 GMT', 'nncoection': 'close', 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8', 'www-authenticate': 'OAuth realm="https%3A%2F%2Fapi.linkedin.com", oauth_problem="parameter_absent", oauth_parameters_absent="oauth_token%26oauth_verifier"'}, 'oauth_problem=parameter_absent&oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_token%26oauth_verifier')
```

It is getting a 400 response saying:

```
oauth_problem="parameter_absent", oauth_parameters_absent="oauth_token%26oauth_verifier"
```

I cannot get an auth_verifier because this is an JSAPI to REST exchange. Is there something different I should be doing for the call?

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass xoauth_oauth2_access_token as a header, but a query parameter.

Comment: Can you provide the HTTP request/response w/headers? It's hard to guess how this library serializes the request.